# Using Abstract Factory pattern and Bridge pattern together

Tags: design-patterns, bridge, abstract-factory

The GoF book mentions that Abstract Factory and Bridge pattern can be used together. However, I cant find any examples of using these two patterns together either in the GoF book or on the internet. I do have an idea on how to use them together, but I am not confident in my approach. I would appreciate if someone can provide a good example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you go to subway to buy a sandwich.

First you choose a bread, then you choose your meat.

You have four choices of bread and four choices of meat.

Without using bridge pattern, you will need to create 16 classes to represent each type of sandwich.

With bridge pattern, you break down the whole situation into abstract bread interface, four concrete bread classes which implement abstract bread interface and they are dependent on the abstract meat implementor(part-whole relationship). Another four concreate meat implementors that implement meat implementor.

```
public interface IBread
{
    void GetSandWich();
} 

// one of the concrete IBread Implementations

public class ItalianCheeseAndHerbBread : IBread
{
    public ItalianCheeseAndHerbBread(IMeatImplentor implementor)
    {
       this.implementor = implementor;
    }

    public override void GetSandWich()
    {
          implementor.doSomething();
    }
}

// one of the four meat implementors
public Chicken : IMeatImplementor
{
    public override void doSomething(){}
}
```

until this point, we have standard bridge pattern.
But now the situation changed a little bit, we need vegetarian sandwich, so we need IVegetableImplementor, now we need to amend the ItalianCheeseAndHerbBread to have multiple constructors. But this will break the cohesion of the class. What we can do is we can have a factory instead, we can pass in this factory so the ItalianCheeseAndHerbBread is no longer dependent on IMeatImplementor or IVegetableImplementor, it's dependent only on IFactory. The factory will be responsible to create meat or vegetable.

This is the best illustration I can think of. Hope it can help a bit.
Here's the uml diagram to clarify the code.
[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how that could be the bridge pattern? Either you or me have fundamentally misunderstood the purpose of the pattern. Either way you need to explain in more detail why the pattern is suitable for your case and which problem it solves.

Comment: Hi mate, could you have a look at the uml diagram and point out which part is wrong please? Maybe I need to rephrase some of my words.

Comment: @Larry, thanks for attempting to answer my question. The intent of the Bridge pattern is to "decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently" that your  example doesn't follow. For e.g., we can implement a Queue using Bridge pattern. The implementation bit of the pattern can implement a queue using any suitable data structure like an array or a linked list or whatever that the abstraction bit of the pattern can use then use to perform queue type operations.

Comment: @Larry, just because the UML diagrams resembles with a pattern it does not make it to an instance of that pattern. For e.g., UML diagrams for State and Strategy patterns are nearly identical, but they are two distinct patterns. It is all about the intent :)

Comment: @Waqas Yes you're right. I totally agree with you about the intent. So let's talk about the intent of my illustration. As I said, we can have four different breads and 4 different meat, a burger will have one bread and one meat, so there're 4 * 4 = 16 different combinations. So that's why I said without using bridge pattern, we would need to create 16 burger classes to represent all of the possibility. Now we have a problem, what if we add one more bread type? This will lead to create 4 more classes. The intent of bridge pattern is  decouple the abstraction and implementation and let them vary

Comment: independently. The benefit is object reusability and encapsulation. We fullfil the intent by decoupling the bread and the meat, and let them vary independently. The benefit is we can reuse these bread the meat and make different combinations. It helps us to reuse the class and make them more maintainable.

Comment: @Larry, you need to pay attention to the word 'its' in the intent of the Bridge pattern. 'meat' should not be an implementation of 'bread'. Would you make bread with meat?

Comment: The intent of the Bridge pattern entails:
1)you define an abstraction an entity with some behaviour
2)entity relies on the implementation to perform requested behaviours
3)as long as contract between abstraction and its implementation is obeyed they both can vary independently
So, my point is mainly to perhaps suggest an improvement to the Bridge pattern bit of the example, may be a abstraction like a 'sandwich' and possible implementations would be more appropriate. Otherwise, it is hard to see how 'meat' is an implementation for abstraction 'bread', whereas all you want is a sandwich :)